# How do I run sbt test with scalatest? I had an error: object scalatest is not a member of package org

Tags: scala, sbt, scalatest

I want to test my code in the following project using scalatest.

```
MyProject/
+ src
  - main/scala/mypackage1/Calc.scala
  - test/scala/mypackage1/CalcTest.scala
- built.sbt
```

built.sbt

```
libraryDependencies += "org.scalactic" %% "scalactic" % "3.2.2"
libraryDependencies += "org.scalatest" %% "scalatest" % "3.2.2" % "test
```

Calc.scala

```scala
package mypackage1

object Calc extends App {
  def add(x: Int, y: Int) = x + y
}
```

CalcTest.scala

```scala
package mypackage1

class CalcTest extends org.scalatest.funsuite.AnyFunSuite {
  test("Calc.add") {
    assert(Calc.add(1, 2) == 3)
  }
}
```

I run `sbt test` in `test/scala/mypackage1` but I got a compile error.
What should I do?

```
[error] /workspaces/MyProject/src/test/scala/myproject1/CalcTest.scala:3:28: object scalatest is not a member of package org
[error] class CalcTest extends org.scalatest.funsuite.AnyFunSuite {
[error]                            ^
```

Comment: Did you reload your sbt project definition before running the tests?

Comment: Which Scala version are you using?

Comment: try `sbt dependencyTree` (in sbt 1.4 and above) to see what jars are being loaded - your libraryDependencies in the description should work but it seems there is an issue your build.sbt

Answer (score 0):

Sorry but I resolved this myself.
I run `stb test` in `MyProject` directory (root directory of the project, not in `test/scala/mypackage1`) and it worked properly.
Thank you for your help.